# Should my chimney cooker hood have a flue?

Tags: kitchens

I have a chimney-style cooker hood over my hob. Today I removed the cover from the chimney, expecting there to be a flue behind it going outside the building, but there wasn't.

Does this mean that the hood has been installed incorrectly? Is it actually doing anything? Shouldn't there be a flue to remove the fumes from my kitchen?

Apologies if this is a stupid question but it seemed odd that my cooker hood should just release the fumes back into my kitchen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic stove/range/hob type hoods. Externally vented would have a flue of some sort that vent smoke ,fumes and odors to the exterior. An internally vented type just filters and recirculates the air back into the kitchen. To make things more confusing most hoods can be set up to operate in either mode. The conversion usually involves installing or removing a metal blocking plate. Both styles require occasional cleaning of the filters to limit grease buildup. I would want to verify that the hood is installed correctly. With the fan on high you should feel air being drawn in and exhausted somewhere. It may be drawn in and exhausted under the hood. Make sure that the unit does not vent into an interior wall cavity or an attic as this would be a fire hazard.

Comment: Well, there certainly isn't a flue anywhere so I guess it must be internally vented. I've just noticed that the ceiling/walls around the top of the hood have quite a lot of greasy build up on them!

How would I spot the metal blocking plate? What does it look like?

Comment: It generally requires removing the unit from the wall.